# Microsoft Report Viewer Control not displaying report

Tags: winforms, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have built a simple report and run it successfully in test winform apps but when I try to run the same report in my production winforms application, the report just doesn't show up in the viewer. I look at the ReportViewer control after InitializeComponent and everything looks fine.

Are there debugging techniques or gotcha's that might be able to point me to why the report is not showing. It feels like there should be an error of some sort but it just displays a blank form.

Comment: Code please. How do you invoke the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a simple mistake.

In implementing the report viewer in a MVP environment, I managed to not notice/implement the RefreshReport in the Form Load. Once I called Refresh Report, the report showed up.